# ld: unknown architecture of input file `shellcode.o' is incompatible with aarch64 output

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, nasm, arm64

I am trying to assemble and link an assembly program, the two commands I use to do so are: nasm -f elf64 shellcode.asm AND ld shellcode.o.

The last command throws an error (watch title), I don't have any idea why and have been trying to find an answer but can't find one.

Here is the code in shellcode.asm:

```
section .text
        global _start

_start:

mov ebx, 0
mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

I use a raspberry pi 4 with kali linux on it.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: AArch64 is an ARM based system, and ELF64 (64-bit AMD/Intel) which you are using as an output format is not understood by the AARCH64 linker. NASM doesn't assemble ARM code. Your code is also 32-bit Linux for Intel compatible processors so it won't work on your platform without a virtual machine or emulator.

Comment: That's not shellcode, it's just a 32-bit x86 Linux executable that makes an `exit` system call.  Its machine code contains `0` bytes so it won't work as shellcode you could inject via a string buffer overflow.  (But as Michael says, your problem is that you're trying to run x86 code on a CPU with a different architecture.)